# Open a panel in a firefox extension using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, panel, xul

I am developing an extension for firefox. I have a panel as follows -

```xml
<panel id = "popup_text" width = "300">
  Text here  
</panel>
```

This pops up when i click on a label using this code :

```xml
<label value="FFWTS" popup="popup_text"/>
```

I want to make this panel popup automatically, using javascript. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [panel.openPopup()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/panel#m-openPopup) or [panel.openPopupAtScreen()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/panel#m-openPopupAtScreen), e.g.:

```js
document.getElementById("popup_text").openPopupAtScreen(200, 200, false);
```